# store.connect(host,username,password) is not Connecting to my gmail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to write a test case which connect to I MAP g mail inbox and retrieve all mails from inbox and process them But the statement  store.connect( host, userName, password ) ; is not connecting to g mail store. No error i am getting when i trace debug output it is like bellow

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.6
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAPS: enable STARTTLS
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "imap.gmail.com", port 993, isSSL true
```

I resolve this problem with below code.

```
MailSSLSocketFactory socketFactory= new MailSSLSocketFactory();
        socketFactory.setTrustAllHosts(true);
        properties.put("mail.imaps.ssl.socketFactory", socketFactory);
.........
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaMail FAQ has [tips for debugging connection problems](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).

Comment: Ya it was SSL problem i resolved it. I vl uodateing code above. thanks