# Unable to connect to SSL-IMAP of Gmail using Javamail 1.4.5

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to connect to my gmail account using Javamail. It does not connect and throws error. Here is my code -

```
public class MailConnection {
    Folder inbox;

public MailConnection() throws MessagingException{
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    props.setProperty("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
     try{
         Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
         session.setDebug(true);
         Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
         store.connect("mailbox.xyz.com", "emailId@xyz.com", "password");
         System.out.println(store);

         inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
         System.out.println("No of Unread Messages : " + inbox.getUnreadMessageCount());
     }
     catch (NoSuchProviderException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
     }
}
```

Here is the debug output as well as the error thrown when i execute the above code. Strange that the same code works in some other systems in the same network.

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.5
DEBUG: getProvider() returning     javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG: trying to connect to host "imap.gmail.com", port 993, isSSL true
javax.mail.MessagingException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path     building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find     valid certification path to requested target;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:     PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:     unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

It is strange that somehow this code works on some other systems.

Comment: got the answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937873/store-connecthost-username-password-is-not-connecting-to-my-gmail?rq=1

Comment: following the above link i could solve the problem on my system.... but some other systems still don't connect to Gmail

Comment: Look for firewalls or anti-virus programs that are preventing the connection.

Answer (score -1):

Disable your antivirus, it is because you have active your email protection.

Comment: It works! You can read this FAQ[https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug] from java mail. `Sometimes a firewall installed on your local machine or on your network will prevent you from connecting to the server.` I disabled my AVG and connected!